# Select when value not in joined table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have two Entities (the entities are simplefied):

Participation

```
[ActiveRecord]    
public class Participation
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [HasMany(...)]
    public IList<ParticipationEvent> GeneratedEvents {get;set;}
}
```

And ParticipationEvent

```
[ActiveRecord]    
public class ParticipationEvent
{
   [PrimaryKey]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [BelongsTo]
   public ProgramParticipation {get;set;}

   [Property]
   public int Code {get;set;}
}
```

where (as you can see) a Participation has many Events. Each event has a unique code.

What I want, is to select all Participations, that DOESN'T have a particular event. How can I do this with NHibernate? I know I can use a INNER JOIN to easily get all instances WITH a certain event, but can this be done the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate/NHibernate support a LEFT OUTER JOIN, which selects all records in table A joined to table B, even if B doesn't have a counterpart. To get those  records in A that are not in B, simply add  WHERE tableB.SoleNonNullableColumn IS NULL. The only way a non-nullable column can be null is because of a row in a LEFT OUTER JOIN, where tableB doesn't show up at all.

Comment: What should be the SoleNonNullableColumn in my case? I'm not sure what the exact HQL would be..

Comment: 'Id' is probably a good candidate. {where ParticipationEvent.Id IS NULL}. See HQL documentation for general info: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html